# How do I know whether my graphics card is supported by fglrx 13.101

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

So I've been reading https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics and according to it I need a graphics card that is supported by fglrx 13.101. My system is a laptop with Intel Integrated Graphics and AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5650 switchable graphics. How do I know whether the AMD graphics card is supported by the driver?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Grammargeek I'd like to switch to the discrete (AMD) card instead of the integrated one.

Answer (score 1):

you can visit the website to see if your card is supported http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

more info https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD